# How do I convert this IE AJAX code to jQuery AJAX call which works?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to call a .NET API which accepts JSON and responds with JSON.

I have a javascript example that is IE only that works.

But when I try to convert the code into a jQuery / AJAX call I am unable to make it work.

I have tried every parameter combination I can think of with no success.

Here's the IE code that works.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

function callService() {
    var url = "http://hrdtssiw01:8700/JsonWCF/DoJsonWork"; //use this url on RDN server for access.
    var body = '{"LevelOneString":"hello world","LevelTwoClass":{"LevelThreeClass":{"LevelThreeString":"Hello Level Three"},"LevelTwoString":"Hello Level Two"}}';

    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xmlHttp.send(body);
}

// Create result handler
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        alert('working!!!!');
        document.getElementById("Text1").value = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}
</script>
```

And here's the jQuery code...

```
<script>
function callAjax() {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    var temp_url = 'http://hrdtssiw01:8700/JsonWCF/DoJsonWork';
    var temp_data = '{"LevelOneString":"hello world","LevelTwoClass":{"LevelThreeClass":{"LevelThreeString":"Hello Level Three"},"LevelTwoString":"Hello Level Two"}}';

    $.ajax(temp_url,
        {
        'type': 'POST',
        'data': temp_data,
        'dataType': 'json',
        'processData': false,
        //'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'headers': {'contentType':'application/json'},     
        'success': function(data) { alert('data: ' + data); },
        'error': function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
         }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#thebutton').click(function() { callAjax(); return false;});
});

</script>
```

In the jQuery example I have contentType commented out.

If I include the contentType the request is sent as JSON, but the body is not set.
If I comment out contentType the body is set correctly, but then the contenType is set to the default.

How can I make this work???

Comment: which is the browser used?

Comment: `CORS` is not supported by IE and it looks like a corss domain request

Answer (score 0):

The `data` object should be an object, unless the server-side is decoding the json. Try changing to

```
var temp_data = {"LevelOneString":"hello world","LevelTwoClass":{"LevelThreeClass":{"LevelThreeString":"Hello Level Three"},"LevelTwoString":"Hello Level Two"}};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cross domain request, you need to be using a CORS supported browser(IE does not support), then try

```
$.ajax(temp_url, {
    'type' : 'POST',
    'data' : temp_data,
    'dataType' : 'json',
    'processData' : false,
    'contentType' : 'application/json',
    'success' : function(data) {
        alert('data: ' + data);
    },
    'error' : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```